# Testing image processing routines with robolectric

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

For my Android application I do require a few image processing routines which I want to test using robolectric. These routines do operate on `Bitmap` objects. In order to do this I need to load testing images. To my great disappointment I discovered that robolectric does not support the `BitmapFactory` class Android framework. They say:

> [Robolectric isn't here to run your entire application on the JVM,
>   it's just here to enable enough functionality exists so that you can
>   test *your* code.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/robolectric/Q0cY7-UYICY/IFDiFRc01iIJ)

So I decided to write my own `Bitmap` loader:

```
public static Bitmap loadFromFile( File file ) throws IOException
{
    final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read( file );
    final int[] pixels = new int[ image.getWidth() * image.getHeight() ];

    image.getRGB
        ( 0                    // start x
        , 0                    // start y
        , image.getWidth()     // width
        , image.getHeight()    // height
        , pixels               // pixel array
        , 0                    // offset
        , image.getWidth() );  // stride

    final Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap
        ( pixels                      // pixel array
        , image.getWidth()            // width
        , image.getHeight()           // height
        , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );  // format

    return result;
}
```

I also wanted to test whether the loader works, so I wrote the short testing routine shown below.

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception
{
    final Bitmap source = loadFromFile( new File( "in.png" ) );
    saveToFile( source, "png", new File( "out.png" ) );
}
```

It uses the following routine for writing the image:

```
public static void saveToFile
    ( Bitmap bitmap
    , String format, File file ) throws IOException
{
    final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage
        ( bitmap.getWidth()               // width
        , bitmap.getHeight()              // height
        , BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );  // channels

    final int[] pixels = new int[ image.getWidth() * image.getHeight() ];

    bitmap.getPixels
        ( pixels                // pixel array
        , 0                     // offset
        , image.getWidth()      // stride
        , 0                     // start x
        , 0                     // start y
        , image.getWidth()      // width
        , image.getHeight() );  // height

    image.setRGB
        ( 0                    // start x
        , 0                    // start y
        , image.getWidth()     // width
        , image.getHeight()    // height
        , pixels               // pixel array
        , 0                    // offset
        , image.getWidth() );  // stride

    ImageIO.write( image, format, file );
}
```

After I run the test, I compare the written `out.png` to the `in.png`. While, of course, `in.png` looks fine, `out.png` is empty. It has the right dimensions, but it is filled with zero-alpha-pixels.

**Question:** What am I doing wrong? How am I supposed to load testing images with robolectric that I require to test *my* image processing routines?

**Note:** If I set all `pixels` entries to 0xFFFFFFFF right before creating the `Bitmap` object, nothing changes. The written image stays all transparent. So I think the mistake must be somewhere later.

I'm using robolectric 2.2.

Comment: Any updates on this one ? I've tried lot's of approaches, but seems like Bitmap is stubbed...

Comment: @saikek Nope, seems like only thing you can do is use an own `Bitmap` abstraction that uses the original `Bitmap` when it is available and falls back to an own implementation otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Well apparently i finished up with this issue by running regular Android tests.
Example:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.test.UiThreadTest;

public class InvadersFromSpace extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<ColorPickerActivity> {

    public InvadersFromSpace() {
        super(ColorPickerActivity.class);
    }

    ColorPickerActivity mainActivity;
    Bitmap forpixels;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        mainActivity = getActivity();
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inScaled = false;
        forpixels = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/sdcard0/photos/IMG_20130815_194838.jpg");
    }

    @UiThreadTest
    public void testImageNormallyLoaded() {
        assertTrue(forpixels.getWidth() == 1716);
        assertTrue(forpixels.getHeight() == 1709);
    }

    @UiThreadTest
    public void testFlagDarkBlue() {
        CompareFewColors(forpixels, 772, 690, new String[]{"DarkMidnightBlue","Charcoal","CoolBlack"}, true);
        CompareFewColors(forpixels, 991, 1269, new String[]{"Arsenic","DarkMidnightBlue","Charcoal"}, false);
    }
}
```

So 2 points that you should take into account:
1) Extending ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
2) Running test with @UiThreadTest attribute. (otherwise when you access ui parameters or bitmaps they have stubs/mocks/old parameters)